# Dealing with columns containing nested json using python pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas df` with various columns. One column - `myCol` - looks like this:

```
df

someCol   myCol
a         [{}]
b         [{'X': {'A': "value", 'B': "value"}}]
c         [{}, {}]
d         [{'X': {'A': "value", 'B': "value", 'C': "value"}}]
```

The maximum number of key-val pairs in `X` is unknown: some rows contain them all, some only contain a selection, and some are empty. I would like to replace `myCol` with actual columns, with as many columns as needed depending on the unique number of key-val pairs in `X`. So in this particular example, I would end up with:

```
df

someCol   A       B       C
a         N/A     N/A     N/A
b         value   value   N/A     
c         N/A     N/A     N/A
d         value   value   value
```

I am struggling in coming up with a general way to solve this, which is needed since I don't know how many 'additional' columns I will need in the end. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi please check out pandas.read_json: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html
And edit your question if you still need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution return first lists and dictionary with key `X`, then convert Nones to empty dicts and last pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
d = [{} if pd.isna(x) else x for x in df.pop('myCol').str[0].str.get('X')]
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(d, index=df.index))
print (df)
  someCol      A      B      C
0       a    NaN    NaN    NaN
1       b  value  value    NaN
2       c    NaN    NaN    NaN
3       d  value  value  value
```

Comment: Thank you. If the values are `True` or `False` instead of `"value"`, how can I adapt your answer to that?

Comment: @CHRD - I think no change.

Comment: True, that didn't matter. Thanks alot!